# Find most occurrences of base 10 number in list

Tags: algorithm

How can I find the most occurences of the same number in below sequence ?

```
1,5,4,3,2,5,3,1,5,3,7,5,7
```

The answer in this case is `5`.

I'm leaning towards adding each number to a list and if the number is already in the list then increment a counter. In this method I think I need to have a counter for each number. What is the solution that is easiest for a person to understand ?

In this case I'm using java

This is an attempt that is not working :

A slight modification of Steph's answer but this works -

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int[] numbers = {1,5,4,3,2,5,3,1,5,3,7,5,7,7,7,7,7};        
        int[] counterArray = new int[numbers.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i){
            counterArray[numbers[i]] = counterArray[numbers[i]] + 1;
        }

        int maxNumber = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i){
            if(counterArray[i] > counterArray[maxNumber])
            {
                maxNumber = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(maxNumber);
    }

}
```

Comment: Define elegant, please? Less space? Less computation time? Less source code? Also, can your numbers be assumed to be small?

Comment: I'm using java, but pseudocode would suffice. By elegant I mean simple for a human to understand the steps.

Comment: @thiton yes numbers will be small, computation time & amount of source code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you O(n) processing time, the memory footprint (not counting the initial array which you have already) is O(1) when you know that your values are going to be between 0 and 9 such that `counterArray = new int[10];`

```
int[] numbers = {1,5,4,3,2,5,3,1,5,3,7,5,7};
//int[] counterArray = new int[10]; // use this if the max value of the in the array 'numbers' is known to be 9
int[] counterArray = new int[numbers.length]; // Use this if the max value of the array is not known.
// or we can quickly iterate O(n) operation to find the max value and use that

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i){
    counterArray[numbers[i]] = counterArray[numbers[i]] + 1;
}

int maxNumber = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i){
    if(counterArray[i] > countarArray[maxNumber])
    {
        maxNumber = i;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Number: " + maxNumber.ToString() + " occurs " + countarArray[maxNumber].ToString() + " times.");
```

Another way to reduce excessive memory usage would be to find the min and max values used O(n) and then create the array to suite that number of values (remember to offset the array position by the min value).

Answer (score 1):

Since you'd like an algorithm that is fast, your proposed solution is indeed the fastest. Initialize an array of size 10 to 0, and then simply:

```
for (int i: arrayList) ++counterArray[i]
```

As a slight average-time optimization, you can just keep a running counter of the most frequent two numbers found, and stop searching if the most common is more than  count ahead of the second most common, where  is the number of numbers yet to be examined.

Comment: I'm missing something, can you take a look at my code posted in question ?

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm One ( with O(n) time complexity and O(1) memory complexity) :**

As what you said, set a counter for each number (10 counters) and scan the list once. C code:

```
//int the_given_array[n];

int counter[10];
int ix, result;
memset(counter,0,10);

for(ix=0; ix<n; ix++) counter[the_given_array[i]]++;

result = 0;
for(ix=1; ix<10; ix++) if(counter[ix]>counter[result]) result = ix;
```

**Algorithm Two ( with O(N^2) time complexity and O(1) memory complexity):**

NOTE: this one has no advantage than the first if you are process base10 numbers (limited numbers) !

Set  a counter for current target number, and scan the list to count it. then count another number and so forth. keep a maximum for the most occurences of the same number. you have to scan the list n times at most. For more speed, you might want to use GPU programming to deal with each number in parallel.

Comment: For algorithm one, it's hardly O(n) memory complexity as there's at most going to be 10 items in the array since we're only dealing with base10 numbers `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`.

Comment: @Seph well then it would be O(1) memory complexity. I misunderstood that it just means decimal notation.